# Google Chrome remote debugging local domain

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, remote-debugging

I'm developing a website on my local machine using myblog.local as a custom domain for that, I have an apache VirtualHost and the name registered on the hosts file of my mac. The thing is when I try to use chrome remote debugging on my USB connected device using myblog.local as an address pushed using the chrome://inspect tool.

I always a not found error.

My question is, do I need to do something extra in order to remotely debug a custom domain registered on my Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Map to custom local domains](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server#custom-domains).

I got it set up once to work with custom local domains, but it took a bit of experimenting. I definitely needed a proxy server to get it working.

Comment: No luck with Map to custom local domains because the usb interface does not provide that service. Over wifi it works but over USB does not.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem on a PC. I followed @Kayce Basques' [Map to custom local domains](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server) guide and after some perseverance everything is now working.

Kayce's guide requires a proxy server, I've included my working configuration for the [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) open source and free proxy server below.

Squid installation was easy, I just downloaded and installed a pre-compiled Windows binary file and the server appeared in my Windows system tray. It should hopefully be equally simple for OSX and Linux platforms.

All configuration is done inside a squid.conf file accessible from the Squid menu. I followed [this simple guide](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/ConfigExamples/Reverse/VirtualHosting) for a Reverse Proxy. Whilst I included everything in that guide I believe the following line is the critical one to get everything working.

```
cache_peer 192.168.0.2 parent 80 0 no-query proxy-only originserver
```

In the above line `192.168.0.2` is my PC's internal IP address and `80` is my Apache virtual host port number defined in my Apache Virtual Hosts file. There's another helpful guide [here](http://derpturkey.com/squid-as-a-reverse-proxy/) but that guide omits the `originserver` option and didn't work on my machine though otherwise helpful.

It seems you *do* need to be connected by USB cable for this to work so I don't quite understand @asolenzal's comment above. Also each time I changed the configuration I ran `Path/to/squid.exe -k reconfigure -n Squid` in a command window to reload Squid. You can find that command [here](https://www.reaper-x.com/2011/10/17/how-to-install-squid-proxy-on-windows/).